# How to split a string by numbering?

Tags: python, regex, string, nltk

I wish to split the following corpus into its parts:

```
corpus = '1  Write short notes on the anatomy of the Circle of Willis including normal variants.     2  Write short notes on the anatomy of the radiological spaces of the orbit excluding the eyeball.      3  Write short notes on the anatomy of the axis (C2 vertebra).      4  Write short notes on the anatomy of the corpus callosum.      5  Write short notes on the anatomy of the posterior division of the internal iliac artery  6  Write short notes on the anal canal including sphincters.               
      '
```

Into the following:

```
['Write short notes on the anatomy of the Circle of Willis including normal variants.', 'Write short notes on the anatomy of the radiological spaces of the orbit excluding the eyeball.', 'Write short notes on the anatomy of the axis (C2 vertebra).', 'Write short notes on the anatomy of the posterior division of the internal iliac artery', 'Write short notes on the anal canal including sphincters.']
```

I wrote this, but doesn't work:

```
for i in [int(s) for s in corpus.split() if s.isdigit()]:
    answer = corpus.split(str(i))

print(answer)
```

What can I do?

Comment: "It doesn't work" may be a correct description, but *how* does it not work?

Comment: If I knew that - I wouldn't be asking you...

Comment: But you *do* know what happens when you run it. Does it give an error? Does it print out garbage? Does your computer shut down?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For your example data, you might also match zero or more times a whitespace followed by one or more digits and 2 times a whitespace to [split](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.split) on:

[`*\d+`](https://regex101.com/r/AQejj4/1)

```
print (filter(None, re.split(' *\d+  ', corpus)))
```

[Demo](http://rextester.com/SQZUUK91090)

You might put the whitespace in a character class followed by a quantifier [`[ ]*\d+[ ]{2}`](https://regex101.com/r/tmKUvt/1/) for clarity.

Answer (score 0):

You tagged [regex](/questions/tagged/regex) but provided a non-regex solution. This is a non-regex correct solution for your OP.

Splitting on spaces is ok, then accumulate text parts into a temporary variable until you encounter the next number, then add the temporary to your overall result.

Using list to store temporarty (parts) is more efficient that appending to a string because of immutability.

Skip storing the numbers itself:

```
corpus = '1  Write short notes on the anatomy of the Circle of Willis including normal variants.     2  Write short notes on the anatomy of the radiological spaces of the orbit excluding the eyeball.      3  Write short notes on the anatomy of the axis (C2 vertebra).      4  Write short notes on the anatomy of the corpus callosum.      5  Write short notes on the anatomy of the posterior division of the internal iliac artery  6  Write short notes on the anal canal including sphincters.'               

allparts = []  # total result
part = []      # parts that belong to one number
for p in corpus.split():
    if p.isdigit():      # if a number
        if part:             # if stored something
            allparts.append(' '.join(part))   # add it to result
            part=[]
        continue         # skip storing the number  

    part.append(p)      # add to part

if part:   # add rest
    allparts.append(' '.join(part))

print(allparts)
```

Output:

```
['Write short notes on the anatomy of the Circle of Willis including normal variants.', 
 'Write short notes on the anatomy of the radiological spaces of the orbit excluding the eyeball.', 
 'Write short notes on the anatomy of the axis (C2 vertebra).', 
 'Write short notes on the anatomy of the corpus callosum.', 
 'Write short notes on the anatomy of the posterior division of the internal iliac artery', 
 'Write short notes on the anal canal including sphincters.']
```

Comment: DV - no comment. How to know what I should improve upon? Solution works, so that can not be it.

Comment: Hello: the cyclomatic complexity ([5](https://imgur.com/a/ectVIQJ) following [lizard](http://www.lizard.ws/) metrix) of your code is quite higher than necessary and, in general, your code is far from pythonic.

Comment: @LucaCappelletti - thanks for the feedback. Mine is a working solution, it is easy understandable and it solves the problem at hand. A oneliner using regex will produce the wanted output - I am in doubt it will give much opportunity to learn something though. If some metric tells me mine is more complex then nessessary I have to disagree.

Answer (score 0):

Using [`re.split`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.split) and list comprehension, using [`str.strip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html) to remove eventual spaces:

```
import re
result = [
    phrase for phrase in map(str.strip, re.split('\d+\s\s', corpus)) if phrase
]
```

**Result:**

```
['Write short notes on the anatomy of the Circle of Willis including normal variants.',
 'Write short notes on the anatomy of the radiological spaces of the orbit excluding the eyeball.',
 'Write short notes on the anatomy of the axis (C2 vertebra).',
 'Write short notes on the anatomy of the corpus callosum.',
 'Write short notes on the anatomy of the posterior division of the internal iliac artery',
 'Write short notes on the anal canal including sphincters.']
```

Comment: It is good custom to explain downvotes, so that the answer may be bettered.

Answer (score -1):

Try using re.split() with Regular Expression + strip()

```
a = "1  hello.  2  my name is. 3  maat."

answer = [s.strip(" ") for s in filter(None, re.split(" *\d+ ", a))]

print(answer) #['hello.', 'my name is.', 'maat.']
```

re.split() is pretty much split() but it contains demilitmer as well
/ strip(" ") removes space from s

Comment: Your answer does not cover when the digits have values greater than 9 and returns also empty strings since it execute strip last, after having run the filter.

Comment: Thank you for your opinion but I didn't understand the last part of your comment. Could you explain it to me if you don't mind?

Comment: Sure: when you have a string `"   "` and you run `.strip` you return an empty list `““`.

Comment: Additionaly, your method splits in the user example at `(C2 vertebra).`

Comment: Oh, Thank you for pointing that out I have edited as you have suggested. I was wrong with regular expression. But, I am not quite sure if he would want to enter " " to the text

Comment: I have edited. Thank you for your delicate feedback!